# Calculate previous and next months from date string

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, hive, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to find the Sales average before and after for selected months over a span of 3 years.

There are two columns, `MONTH` and `SELECTED_MONTH`. Both of these are in the same format which is string (eg. `201103`). I need to select the particular month in `SELECTED_MONTH` and get the previous and next month of that month in `MONTH`.

For example: I have `201103` in `SELECTED_MONTH`. I need to get the previous and next months in `MONTH` using that value, so `201102` and `201104`.

Any help would be appreciated. I tried different ways which won't work. I use HIVE but even queries in SQL would help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do or why yo think SQL might be useful for that task

Comment: Use  `RIGHT(SELECTED_MONTH,2)` to get the month, then do a between `RIGHT(SELECTED_MONTH, 2) - 1 and RIGHT(SELECTED_MONTH, 2) + 1`. You will have to do some casting to integers but that should put you on the right trach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL offers powerful, but slightly clunky, date arithmetic functions. The functions [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) allow translation from dates represented as text strings to the DBMS's internal `DATE` and `DATETIME` formats.

If you happen to have a text column, called, for example, `month`, in your SQL table, with text dates of the form `201503` (`YYYYmm`), you can use MySQL date arithmetic to do what you want.

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(month,'01'),'%Y%m%d')
```

produces the DATE of the first day of the month mentioned.

```
LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(month,'01'),'%Y%m%d'))
```

produces the date of the last day of `month`.

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(month,'01'),'%Y%m%d') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

produces the DATE of the first day of the preceding month.

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(month,'01'),'%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

produces the DATE of the first day of the next month.

Carrying this a little further, you can get the `YYYYmm` format for the first day of the preceding quarter like this.

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201505','01'),'%Y%m%d') - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER, '%Y%m')
```

The monkey business of converting between text-string dates and internal dates drives most database designers to store date values internally columns that have the `DATE` datatype.